# Struts2 radio button customization

Tags: html, struts2

I have this radio button in html

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="1"> Gray Scale<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" width="200">

<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2"> Old Style<br>

</td><td align="left" valign="top" width="200">

<input type="radio" name="group1" value="3"> Sharpening<br></td></tr>
```

but I using this Struts code will give me all over the place with no size and anything  `<s:radio name="option" list="#{'1':'Gray Scale', '2':'Old Style','3':'Sharpening'}" value="1" />`

How can I have this radio button for struts 2s individually?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `<s:radio>` tag to render exactly as you want, you have to modify the Struts2 theme that you are using.

Here you have an example from a guy that solves a similar problem: [Struts 2 How To Customize The Theme That Controls How A Struts 2 Tag Is Displayed In The Browser](http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2010/8/10/Struts-2-How-To-Customize-The-Theme-That-Controls-How-A-Struts-2-Tag-Is-Displayed-In-The-Browser)

Comment: Thank you I am reading it now , I thought this might work, but I dont think it will

Comment: <s:radio property="option" name="option" value="1" />

Comment: Maybe this will help to you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809211/how-to-make-struts-radio-tag-create-a-vertical-list-of-radio-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it more clear what already have been described in good way by `Pigueiras`,Struts2 uses theme concept to render the HTML for the Struts2 based tags and internally it uses freemarker tempelates to generate HTML for you.

out of the box S2 comes with following three themes

1. xhtml
2. css_xhtml theme
3. simple
4. ajax (with deprecated DOJO tags)

By default S2 uses xhtml theme to render the HTML and under this theme it will generate certain tables to render the view.

it provides a way to customize the theme or you can define your own theme and can control the way HTML is being generated by the S2.

have a look at following doc for more details

1. [struts-2-themes](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/struts-2-themes.html)
2. [themes-and-templates](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/themes-and-templates.html)
3. [creating_a_theme](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/creating_a_theme)