# How to vertically align radio buttons in Struts2

Tags: struts2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Struts radio tag create a vertical list of radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809211/how-to-make-struts-radio-tag-create-a-vertical-list-of-radio-buttons)

How to vertically align radio buttons in Struts2, as the generated radio buttons are aligned horizontally by default.
I am iterating it over a list.

```
<s:radio theme="simple" list="masterList" name="selectedDatabase" onclick="gotoAction(this)"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's better to ask google and/or stackoverflow first before you post a question here. @anu posted previously the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809211/how-to-make-struts-radio-tag-create-a-vertical-list-of-radio-buttons

Comment: Thank u....will take care of that from the next time :) Thanks again !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<s:iterator value="masterList"> 
  <s:radio theme="simple" name="selectedDatabase" list="#{id:name}"/><br>
</s:iterator>
```

where `id` will be the property of the list, you want to submit and `name` will be the label of the radio button.

Comment: The example code did not work for me but list="#{key:value}" worked for me.