# how to change color of Struts 1.3 HTML Radio button

Tags: struts, struts-1

I am using Apache Struts, version 1.3 HTML form.
I'd like to change the color of the radio button. Please see below, the line of code corresponding to the radio button :

```
<html:radio property="search.dateRange" style = "color:red;" value="demo" />
```

I was expecting the radio button to be red, but it does not work.

Comment: Could you define not working ? what gets red right now ? From reading what you wrote, the property you changed is the text. "Color" property in CSS is related to text, not radio  style (like border, and state style)
What might interesing you is this answer about theme : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5809894/632926 and if you need to understand how to create your own theme, go there: https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/

Comment: @gabrielstuff Struts 1 CSS questions aren't related to Struts 2 at all.

Comment: hello @DaveNewton, perhaps you have a solution to propose ? From what I know about Struts, trying to change style using property like "color" does not help to do anything, except for text. Looking at the doc : struts-1.3.10/docs/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#struts-html.tld, available here: http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/documentation/, the style refers to CSS. 
As for the theme, indeed it applies for Struts 2 ONLY. Sorry to mislead you with this link.

Answer (score 0):

<html:radio property="search.dateRange" style = "accent-color:red;" value="demo" />

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).